# How npm outh-oidc libraries request access token from redirect URI?

Tags: angular, authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, pkce

We are trying to use npm library - angular-oauth2-oidc to perform PKCE based OIDC authentication and authorisation in our angular project .
We have our home page configured as the redirect URI .
How does the npm library internally intercept the access code request and exchange it for access and id token .Does the library use any request interceptors internally?

How can we debug this exchange of auth code for access token ?

Comment: PKCE is usally used on SPAs, so you could just open the developer tools in chrome and see the requests and redirects in the network tab.

The redirect uri has to be configured correctly. For SPAs, you might run into CORS errors, if the auth server is on a different domain than the SPA.